# Log Request/Responses from Azure SDK for .Net

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-management

I am using the Microsoft Azure SDK for .Net in an application and it is throwing an internal "Task Cancelled" exception when processing a request.

Is there a way I can turn on http request/response logging to track down what is causing the issue?

Comment: lots of info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-log-audit and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Comment: @Fuzzybear I am refering to the clientside which is using Azure SDK to send/receive requests, I need to log what it is sending/receiving before failing on the clientside.

Comment: _" I am refering to the clientside which is using Azure SDK to send/receive requests"_ Sending requests to what? An app service, a cloud service, a function app, an app service, a queue...? And what is the "client side"? A console app? A web site? A desktop app? This question is unclear and as it stantds too broad to be answered.

Comment: If you want to catch the sending and receiveing requests, you could use fiddler to capture them